# How to make strings in object optional with Validate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, ecmascript-6

When I run the below PoC, I get

```
ValidationError: Alert.one is not allowed.
ValidationError: Alert.two is not allowed.
ValidationError: Alert must be of type Array.
```

where I would like all the strings in `Alert` to be optional.

Can someone figure out how to do that?

```
const Schema = require('validate');

const p_schema = new Schema({
  Alert: {
    each: { type: String },
    required: false
  },
},{strict: true});

let p = {
  Alert: {
    one: 'x',
    two: 'x'
  }
};

console.log(p_schema.validate(p));
```

Comment: can't you remove required: true?

Comment: I have now tried to remove it, and then setting it to `false`. I get the same error...

Answer (score -1):

It seems it's the type of Alert is wrong, even though I believe you are setting each value of Alert to string, but Alert type is not specified. Try either adding `type: object`, or define Alert as a list not object.
Try the below:

```
const p_schema = new Schema({
  Alert: {
    type: object,
    each: { type: String },
    required: false
  },
},{strict: true});
```